# python3 convert str to bytes-like obj without use encode

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I wrote a httpserver to serve html files for python2.7 and python3.5.

```
def do_GET(self):

     ...
     #if resoure is api
         data = json.dumps({'message':['thanks for your answer']})

     #if resource is file name
         with open(resource, 'rb') as f:
             data = f.read()

    self.send_response(response)
    self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write(data) # this line raise TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

the code works in python2.7, but in python 3, it raised the above the error.

I could use `bytearray(data, 'utf-8')` to convert str to bytes, but the html is changed in web.

[image]

**My question:**
 How to do to support python2 and python3 without use 2to3 tools and without change the file's encoding.

is there a better way to read a file and sent it content to client with the same way in python2 and python3 ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to open your file in *binary* mode, not in *text* mode:

```
 with open(resource,"rb") as f:
     data = f.read()
```

then, `data` is a `bytes` object in python 3, and a `str` in python 2, and it works for both versions.

As a positive side-effect, when this code hits a Windows box, it still works (else binary files like images are corrupt because of the endline termination conversion when opened in text mode).

Comment: you mean in python 3, then. In that case just convert your return value to `bytes(return_value,"ascii")` only if python 3. Test the version with `if sys.version_info >= (3,):`